# Applescript to manipulate VLC

Tags: shell, applescript, vlc, automator

I want to do a script, that it can launch VLC player, and in VLC player "Open a file", then 
"Select a folder", then click on "add" then "play" it. I think that Automator can't do this. But Applescript seems legit, right?

How to build an easy script, that I can save as an application then setup it to the startup folder?

Path : the folder in question `/Users/server_raagc/Copy`

(I tried automator, then applescript, then terminal with a .plist then another automator combined with an applescript saved as application, all of this in a different way times 36.

My code :

```
set workflowpath to "/Users/server_raagc/Desktop/FINAAAAAL - copie.workflow" 
set qtdworkflowpath to quoted form of (POSIX path of workflowpath) 
set command to "/usr/bin/automator " & qtdworkflowpath 
set output to do shell script command
```

Always an error.

The automator Test:

[image: image desc]

Comment: We are not here to do your job for you. Show the script you HAVE written and we can try help fix that.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mean that, look a this 

 `code` set workflowpath to "/Users/server_raagc/Desktop/FINAAAAAL - copie.workflow"
set qtdworkflowpath to quoted form of (POSIX path of workflowpath)
set command to "/usr/bin/automator " & qtdworkflowpath
set output to do shell script command `code`

Comment: don't post code in comments. it's unreadable. edit your question and pot it into a proper code block.

Comment: Hi, I gave a descriptive title and stripped your question of all unrelated content, the focus is on the issue at hand, nothing else; check the guide [About]. . . . Note that we are not supposed to post the same question in two sites of the network, but make a research at [apple.se] and maybe post a new question there with new info that you gather.

Comment: Thank you @Brasofilo, now i understand how to post next time.
In fact one of de automator is a watch me do workflow, it's maybe that?

Comment: I'm not experienced with Automator... research [**here**](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bautomator%5D+watch+me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple `AppleScript` script open a folder in VLC, VLC add files in playlist and play the first file.

> tell application "VLC" to open "/Users/server_raagc/Copy/"

Comment: As simple as that ! you solved my problem and 27 hours of test, by a simple line thank you!